# How to push the result from a loopback findById method into ctx.result

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, loopback

I am able to push the result from inside the findById function and also the log prints correctly, but outside the forEach loop it is just empty. I did try to use promise but that also did not work.

```js
let finalData = [];
Model.afterRemote('find', function(ctx, instance, next) {
  if (ctx.result) {
    if (Array.isArray(ctx.result)) {
      ctx.result.forEach(function(result) {
        Model.findById(result.id, {
            include: {
              relation: 'users',
              scope: {
                fields: ['email']
              }
            }
          },
          function(err, response) {
            finalData.push(response);
            console.log(finalData); // has the user information
          });
      });
    }
    ctx.result = finalData;
    console.log(ctx.result); // --> empty result (need the finalData result)
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: I found out that the first get request is empty, but the subsequent get requests returns the proper data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you call the remote method using a filter? Your way brings to N+1 queries which are very inefficient. There is no need to implement a `afterRemote` in your use case. Use the following filter in your API call:

```js
{
  "include": {
    "relation": "users",
    "scope": {
      "fields": ["email"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I noticed that the number of results increased for subsequent requests.

Comment: just a minor change to the filter, had to enclose the strings with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about the async functions and the order of commands.

Although I think you could just make a different query to your API to achieve what you need.

But anyway, I would call your function rather like this:

```
Model.afterRemote('find', function(ctx, instance, next) {
  let finalData = [];
  if (ctx.result) {
    if (Array.isArray(ctx.result)) {
      // map your results to array of id's
      const ids = ctx.result.map(res => res.id);
      // get result with different search query
      const response = await Arscenes.find({where: {id: {inq: ids}}}, {
          include: [{
            relation: 'users',
            scope: {
              fields: ['email']
            }
          }]
        });
        // put the reuslts in ctx.result
      ctx.result = response;
      // call next() to end the call
      next();
    }
  } else {
    // call next() to end the call only in else case, in your example you're calling that before anything else so the request is over
    next();
  }

});
```

Comment: i modified your code to use promise but the returned val does not include the users.

Comment: sorry, it had a mistake, now it should work (filter was wrong, it should be: `{where: {...}, include: [{...}]